# Adding a function in wordpress which returns true if the login has failed

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm kinda bad at wordpress since I don't (and I wouldn't like to) want to learn it that much, but one of my jobs require me to write some modules in it so that's why I've come for help here.

I'd like to have a function which I can call from a site like this.

```
<?php if (wp_login_failed()): ?>
    <h1>Bad username or password!</h1>
<?php endif ?>
```

I know nothing about these hooks and actions I only need a function which I could call to check if the login has failed.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you Googled anything?

Comment: Check here: https://pippinsplugins.com/redirect-to-custom-login-page-on-failed-login/

Comment: Lee - of course I did, but none of them fit my case.
mitkosoft - thanks for your help, that's what I need!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `is_user_logged_in()` function, it will return true if the current user exists and is logged in.

Best way to learn about wordpress is to start by googling and checking the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope, I'm not looking for that function since I only want that sentence to be displayed if the user has FAILED to log in. If he enters the site where the login form is, I wouldn't want him/her to see that he entered a bad username and/or password since he/she didn't enter anything yet.